# How to install Ubuntu 19.04 live server on Hyper-V VM?

Tags: server, system-installation, 19.04, hyper-v

When I try to install Ubuntu 19.04 live server, after the initial language and "Install Ubuntu Server" selection, but before all the configurations menus the setup flashes some text abruptly a few times and then goes to black screen with blinking cursor.

I read the "black screen" question and answers, but that didn't help, as I tried `nomodeset` option and that didn't fix anything. And when I try `noacpi` the setup *does* get to the configuration menus, but fails to see any hardware, such as network and hard drive, so it still isn't usable.

The 18.10 installer runs without issue on the same VM, so there is nothing broken about its settings.

The problem doesn't seem to occur on Virtual Box, so there is something about the combination of Hyper-V and Ubuntu 19.04 installer that causes trouble, so is it possible to install on a Hyper-V VM and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually got 19.04 installed on Hyper-V Gen 2 VM.
I used a 754MiB ubuntu-19.04-server-amd64.iso from "Alternate download options" instead of the normal 748MiB ubuntu-19.04-live-server-amd64.iso image.
I don't know what's the difference between "live-server" image and "server" image and anyway, the "server" image works.

Comment: Not sure why this is  the way, but I encountered the same issue with a `squashfs` error on boot of the installer.

Comment: Same Problem here! Windows Hyper-V Server 2016 does not work with ubuntu-19.04-**live**-server-amd64.iso (flicker some text) but works with ubuntu-19.04-live-server-amd64.iso

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the bug blocking you https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1831453 . 
Regarding live-server vs server install, the live-server installer uses the subiquity package, which is the one having an issue. This post explains it https://serverfault.com/questions/930163/what-is-the-difference-between-ubuntu-server-and-ubuntu-server-live